# Effective Potential of experienced by a particle with contact interaction in an optical lattice

Tags: condensed-matter, cold-atoms

Suppose i have an optical lattice with particles loaded onto it, the potential due to the optical lattice is $V_{0}Cos\left(x\right)$. Assume that the particles interact with eachother through contact interaction $C*\left|\Psi\right|^{2}$ where $\Psi$ is the mean field wavefunction. what will be the effective potential.
(From sources i know the answer is $frac({V_{0}Cos\left(c\right)})({1+4C})$ but how?